# Search functions in admin panel wordpress not working for numeric numbers search

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-hook, wordpress-admin

In WooCommerce Version 4.2.2 on admin products list i try to do a search in the admin panel for products it returns too many results and this does not happen to all products, some work and it only brings me 1 single product, others bring more. My products have skus numeric number 1,2,3....  and tags like 1c, 2c, 3c.......
So when I do a search I want the result should be only the product number.

I tried to reinstall all Wordpress, WooCommerce and WooCommerce product search, without any change. I tested other search plugins with the same results.

Any help please?

Comment: Does the backend search work like you want it to, when you deactivate the WooCommerce Product Search plugin? If so, you’d need to look into how that plugin performs/manipulates the search query, if not, then this is probably due to default WooCommerce functionality, then you’d have to gon and check what hooks are available to manipulate the search query that creates.

Comment: The backend dosent work when I deactivate plugin. Can you guide me to some documentation about hooks available to manipulate searq query.

Comment: I can’t tell whether you are talking about the default WC product search functionality here, or somethign that was enhanced or replaced by the mentioned plugin. If it is the default search, then you probably need to use the `woocommerce_product_pre_search_products` filter, that gets used in the `search_products` method, https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT.html#1480

Comment: There isn’t any really good documentation for that filter that I could find on a quick search, maybe you’ll have more luck, otherwise this’ll probably require analyzing the coding of that method some more to figure it out.

Comment: I think if you want to search specifically for the product by sku then perhaps you want to look at filters rather than search. Search tends to be fuzzy. There is a hook called `woocommerce_products_admin_list_table_filters` that allow you to add a filter to the admin list, you can use that to add a text input for the sku. Then you can use the hook `woocommerce_product_pre_search_products` like @CBroe suggested and check the $_GET array for your filter field.